# Automated Testing Parallely across browsers (Selenium + Mocha )

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, mocha

I need to write automated tests for jQuery based plugins using Selenium WebDriver and Mocha. I have 3 questions.

1.`mocha test` command is used to start the test. If I need to do the tests parallelly in all the browsers, how would I achieve it? By looping through the test suites using different browser plugins or is there a better way to achieve this?

2. My Test cases mostly involve checking with the attributes and content of the DOMElement. Can't I use selenium web driver just to open the browser and deal every other with plain javascript instead of using Selenium API to get the element, and do some actions on the button like performing Click Operation? Mocha allows this when it is run in the browser.

3. In which case, should I use build tools like Grunt or Gulp for my test cases? Kindly explain this with an example.